# How to enter AX 2012 pretending to be other user?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I need to enter in AX 2012 from my windows user with admin privileges and the same time in the current session I need enter as another user without admin privileges. For example, User GLOBAL\jbravetti.

Comment: You may want to take a look in the [help/on-topic] what questions are on topic for Stack Overflow. This question is not programming related and probably better suited for the [Super User](http://superuser.com/) Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to hold the Shift key and right-click the AX executable, then select "Run as different user" and enter the username and password.

Comment: Yes it's true! but this way you can't choose the environment, for example Production, Test, DEV. Thanks.

Comment: Sure you can - create a shortcut to the AX32.exe and pass an appropriate cmd line option in the shortcut's properties to point to your desired .axc. Then do "Run as diff. user" on that shortcut

Answer (score 1):

After much research I found the answer.

I create a file with .bat extension, edit the file and put this:

```
runas /savedcred /user:DOMAIN\User "AX executable path  -regconfig=path of .axc file"
```

Example:

```
runas /savedcred /user:GLOBAL\jbravetti "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Client\Bin\Ax32.exe -regconfig=C:\AXShortcuts\DEV_CUS.axc"
```

Execute the .bat file, put the password to current user in file and then you access in AX by this user.

I hope it helps.